# Confused about NSCFTimer... what is it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, class, nstimer

Could someone tell me what exactly NSCFTimer is? I get it when I ask NSTimer for a timer.
My problem is that I'm trying to check if an object (supposedly an NSTimer, note the word "supposedly" which is why I'm checking) is an object of class NSTimer, it doesn't seem to work. Does this "NSCFTimer" in any way... hinder the process?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSCFTimer` is an implementation detail of the Foundation and CoreFoundation frameworks.   It is a subclass of `NSTimer` and, thus, `isKindOfClass:` will work just fine.

It does beg the question, though, of why you might have a reference to an object that might or might not be a Timer.   The only sources of timers are either of your creation or well defined methods within the frameworks.  Thus, such uncertainty is both atypical and oft indicates an underlying design problem.

Comment: I was using an array to store timers and other objects at the same time... I've changed it, it wasn't a very good idea to start with. :) thanks.

Comment: Excellent.  We all succumb to the siren call of über-dynamism at some point in our programming life.

Answer (score 4):

bbum put it quite nicely, but to be more blunt: as far as you need to know, `NSCFTimer` is the same thing as `NSTimer`, and you needn't worry about it. :)

**The technical reason:** `NSTimer` is toll-free bridged with `CFRunLoopTimer`. When you instantiate `NSTimer`, the code in that class replaces your instance with an instance of the Core Foundation opaque C type `CFRunLoopTimer`. `CFRunLoopTimer` identifies itself to the Objective-C runtime as an instance of the class `NSCFTimer`, so the class of an instance of `NSTimer` will be reported as `NSCFTimer`.

For more information about toll-free bridging, Core Foundation, and how often you use both without even knowing it, see [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/corefoundation/).